# Android Capture Call button

Tags: android, phone-call

I am new to android ,how can I know if the call button is pressed or i can replace default dialer activity using my dialer I have used following code

```
<receiver  android:name="CallService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and here is my broadcast

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String mAction = intent.getAction();

    Log.e("Intent", mAction);
}
```

But its not receiving any intent

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910339/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-intent/1910599#1910599).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to launch my activity even if I register it using <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Neo, did you able to catch Call activity? If yes, please share the solution to handle action call.