# onReceive method doesn't get called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```
public class BroadcastTest extends Activity {
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try{
    receiver=new Receiver(this);
    registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON));
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

and another class

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public Receiver(BroadcastTest broadcastTest) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Fired","Hi");
}
}
```

is onReceive method of receiver class supposed to be called when i press call button?if yes then it is not geting call.What i am doing wrong here.I am not seeing anything in logcat while pressing call button.Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910339/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-intent

Answer (score 7):

This [Blog post](http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2011/07/05/why-my-broadcastreceiver-does-not-get-called/) describes some common pitfalls with AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver. Examples included! Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Some common pitfalls:

1. Receiver not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

   Declare the receiver in the Manifest-file:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="net.fusonic.testapp.receivers.TestAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
   ```
2. Receiver in the Manifest xml is misspelled

   Always remember that the whole Android-System is case sensitive. So check your spelling is correct in the AndroidMainfest.xml. Remember that the eclipse refactoring functions do not change packagename correctly if you use the short form like “.receivers.TestAlarmReceiver“.
3. PendingIntent requestCode missing?

   If you create a PendingIntent for your Receiver, please add a `requestCode` – even it is a random number! Without your “onReceive” code never get called!
4. AVD running for a long time (very tricky)

   Be aware of using the AVDs especially if your working with “REALTIME_WAKEUP”  and SystemClock… So if you try to test your alarm, please restart the AVD or test on a real device!

Comment: Simply placing a link to your own blog post is frowned upon on Stack Overflow.  Why don't you expand your answer to describe these pitfalls here, rather than forcing everyone to go to your website?

Comment: because i have to write the same content here.. -> would that be better solution?

Comment: Yes, this is much better, because now people who read the question can read your answer here instead of having to go to another site.  Also, what happens if your site moves, changes link locations, or goes down at some point in the future?  It's fine to send people to your site for supplemental information, as long as you present the body of your answer to the question here.

Comment: it worked for me instead of short `.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver` i have put the full path `rss.univ.alarmManager.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Aaaand the link just broke… (That's why it's a good idea to include some content here).

Comment: I was using genymotion and the alarm wasn't working, but as soon as I used my real device the alarm fired. So if you are using an AVD or genymotion check to see if the alarm works on an Android device before spending hours trying to debug bugless code.