# OnRecieve method from BroadCastReciever not being called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have my notifications set up like this

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day - 1);
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.AM);

            Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(), Receiver.class);
            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            if (alarmManager!= null) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
            }
```

Then On my Broadcast Reciever `OnRecieve` I have it set up like this

```
Log.d("Notifiction", "notificationCreated");
```

So that I can check if it's being called.

I also have my manifest set up for this as well,

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity.Receiver" android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I've checked with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583724/9554176) but it still does not work.

Comment: It's not _OnRecieve_, it should be `OnReceive`. It's not _BroadCastReciever_, it should be `BroadCastReceiver`. It's not _Notifiction_, it should be `Notification`. Please correct all the typo on your code and in your post.

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be a lot of questions around broadcast receivers recently.

from [Broadcast Receiver Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts):

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers. If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically). You can still use a context-registered reciever when the user is actively using your app.
>
> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

Please read the [BroadcastReceiver Overview Page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` begins with **1** not 0

> int DAY_OF_MONTH
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. This is a synonym for DATE. The first day of the month has value 1.

May be this is the problem? You passed past date

And the above answer is not suitable to your question

Comment: I set the -1 because I want the notification to popup a day before it was set.