# how to invoke an activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

Could some one please tell me how to invoke an activity from a service when the service receives some content from a server. the service keeps getting the data and the activity needs to update itself.

I am unable to find a good tutorial for broadcast intents stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?
[Clicketh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909812/how-to-use-intents-from-a-service-or-broadcast-receiver)

Actually this might be exactly what you need - 
[How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: you should post duplicate questions as comments not answers

Comment: I agree, its just that I dont have enough rep for that :)